# javascript captcha validation part return the whole form instead of proceed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I'm using a contact form from [elated.com](http://www.elated.com/articles/slick-ajax-contact-form-jquery-php/) and I try to implement a basic math captcha. However, when I submit the form, regardless the captcha is correct or wrong, it pop out the error message of wrong captcha instead of submitting the form.

This part of code is the one I edited:

```
function submitForm() {
    var contactForm = $(this);
    if ( !$('#senderName').val() || !$('#senderEmail').val() || !$('#message').val() ) {

        $('#incompleteMessage').fadeIn().delay(messageDelay).fadeOut();
        contactForm.fadeOut().delay(messageDelay).fadeIn();

    } 
    // this is the part of the code I added the captcha verification.
    if(('#captcha') != captcha_c) {
        $("#captchaError").slideDown(500);
        $("#captchaError").delay(messageDelay).slideUp(500);
    } else {

            $('#sendingMessage').fadeIn();
            contactForm.fadeOut();

            $.ajax( {
            url: contactForm.attr( 'action' ) + "?ajax=true",
            type: contactForm.attr( 'method' ),
            data: contactForm.serialize(),
            success: submitFinished
        });
    }

  return false;
}
```

The HTML form:

```
<form id="contactForm" action="processForm.php" method="post">
    <h2>Send us an email...</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="senderName">Your Name</label>
            <input id="senderName" maxlength="40" name="senderName" placeholder="Please type your name" required="required" type="text" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="senderEmail">Your Email Address</label>
            <input id="senderEmail" maxlength="50" name="senderEmail" placeholder="Please type your email address" required="required" type="email" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="message" style="padding-top: .5em;">Your Message</label>
            <textarea id="message" cols="80" maxlength="10000" name="message" placeholder="Please type your message" required="required" rows="10"></textarea>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label id="captcha" for="captcha"></label>
            <input id="captcha" name="captcha" placeholder="Enter the captcha" required="required" type="text" />
            <script type="text/javascript">
                generate_captcha('captcha');
            </script>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="formButtons">
        <input id="sendMessage" name="sendMessage" type="submit" value="Send Email" />
        <input id="cancel" name="cancel" type="button" value="Cancel" />
    </div>
</form>
<div id="sendingMessage" class="statusMessage">
    <p>Sending your message. Please wait...</p>
</div>
<div id="successMessage" class="statusMessage">
    <p>Thanks for sending your message! We&#39;ll get back to you shortly.</p>
</div>
<div id="failureMessage" class="statusMessage">
    <p>There was a problem sending your message. Please try again.</p>
</div>
<div id="incompleteMessage" class="statusMessage">
    <p>Please complete all the fields in the form before sending.</p>
</div>
<div id="captchaError" class="statusMessage">
    <p>Are you sure about your calculations?</p>
</div>
```

If I remove out the comment part, the form is working and proceed to send the email, where did I go wrong in my javascript part?

Here is the **[working live example](http://omgmobile.my/jeffchew/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
if(('#captcha') != captcha_c) {
```

to this:

```
if($('#captcha').val() != captcha_c) {
```

Also you have the same id for your label as your input so change this:

```
<label id="captcha" for="captcha"></label>
```

to

```
<label id="something_else" for="captcha"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `$` sign before `('#captcha')`
in `if(('#captcha') != captcha_c)`.

Comment: could you print $('#captcha').val() and captcha_c using console.log?

Comment: how do I do that? I know in php I can use `var_dump()` but I'm totally new in javascript

Comment: add `console.log($('#captcha').val());console.log(captcha_c);` right above `if(('#captcha') != captcha_c) {`. And you will see there value in the console of the browser.